# More information gives better estimation error

Tags: probability, statistics

I saw this inequality stated as a fact in our textbook:

$$E[(X - E[X \mid Y, Z])^2] \le E[(X - E[X \mid Y])^2]$$

Intuitively, I can understand what it is saying. But how would we prove such a relationship without knowing anything about $X$, $Y$, and $Z$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$, it is a theorem that for $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^n$ and $W:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^m$, the [Minimum Mean Squared Error (MMSE) predictor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_mean_square_error#Definition) of $X$ given $W$ is $E[X\mid W]$ when all the required moments exist; i.e., for all functions $g:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$,
$$E\,[\,\|X-E[X\mid W]\|^2\,] \le E\,[\,\|X-g(W)\|^2\,].$$
Taking $n=1, m=2$, $W=(Y,Z)$ and $g(Y,Z)=E[X\mid Y]$ gives the desired result:
$$E[(X-E[X\mid Y,Z])^2] \le E[(X-E[X\mid Y])^2].$$
Note that here we've chosen $g: (y,z)\mapsto E[X\mid y].$ 
Proof of the above theorem can be found in online articles, e.g. [here](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-minimum-mean-square-error-estimator-the-conditional-expectation) for an elementary version.